# emmeans output from bayesglm object

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

Is the interval in the output of emmeans function using a bayesglm object a confidence interval or credible interval?

Thank you very much.

```
  rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
  library(arm)
  library(emmeans)

  set.seed(1)
  n <- 100
  x1 <- rbinom (n, 1, .5)
  b1 <- 2
  y <- rbinom (n, 1, invlogit(b1*x1))
  X1 <- factor(x1)

  GLM <- bayesglm (y ~ X1, family=binomial)
  anova(GLM, test = "Chisq")
  EMM <- emmeans(GLM,~X1);EMM
  plot(EMM)

  X1 emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
  0   0.256 0.277 Inf    -0.287     0.799
  1   1.561 0.375 Inf     0.827     2.295
```

Comment: What is displayed there is definitely a confidence interval. But note also that `anova()` is a frequentist analysis. A clue would he to look at `class(GLM)`. I think there is not emmeans support for bayesglm objects, so it may inherit the glm methods if that class is included.

Comment: Thank you very much, Prof. Lenth! Is that confidence interval given by emmeans using a bayesglm object interpretable, in a frequentist paradigm? I'm asking this because I have a logistic model with perfect separation for one of my groups (one group has 0% rate) and I'm using bayesglm to overcome this issue (I'm interested in the frequentist approach), and I want to estimate the CI for the parameters. Best.

Comment: I really don't know. it appears to be frequentist summaries derived from a Bayesian method but you would have to look at the documentation. I have not used that package.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, Prof. Length!

Comment: I finally got a chance to take a look at `bayesglm`. It is very closely based on `glm` architecture and I am pretty confident that the existing support for `glm` objects in **emmeans** should work pretty well.

Comment: Prof Lenth, I really appreciate your time spent solving this issue! Best wishes.